# Sscanf not converting from command line parameter string to IEEE float Nasm x86 Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, command-line-arguments, nasm, scanf

First of all I would like to thank anyone who replies to this, your help is greatly appreciated!

I am trying to get command line parameters (in the code below, just a single parameter) and convert them to floats using sscanf(). I pass the address of the location I want to store the floating point number in (`temp`), a pointer to the string I wish to convert (`dword [ecx + 4]`), and the format string. However, after calling sscanf(), I find that the value I initialized temp with is unchanged. Clearly, I am using sscanf() incorrectly. What am I doing wrong?

```
EXTERN printf
EXTERN sscanf 
GLOBAL main

SEGMENT .data
formd:      DB "%d", 10, 0
formf:      DB "%f", 10, 0 
format:     DB "%f", 0 
temp:       DD 1.1235                   ; where I want the number to go, initialized with some arbitrary non zero number

SEGMENT .text
main:
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp, esp
        mov     ebx, [ebp + 8]          ; number of params
        mov     ecx, [ebp + 12]         ; &(parameter table) 

        pushad                          ; print out the number of parameters
        push    ebx                 
        push    formd
        call    printf
        add     esp, 8 
        popad

        pushad                          ; get number
        push    temp                    ; pass the address of the destination
        push    dword [ecx + 4]         ; pass the first command line parameter 
        push    format                  ; pass the format string 
        call    sscanf                  ; convert it to floating point 
        add     esp, 12
        popad

        pushad                          ; print out temp with FPU 
        finit
        fld     dword [temp]
        sub     esp, 8
        fstp    qword [esp]
        push    formf
        call    printf
        add     esp, 12 
        popad

        pop     ebp
        ret
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have the parameters of `sscanf` switched.

You have:

```
        push    temp                    ; pass the address of the destination
        push    dword [ecx + 4]         ; pass the first command line parameter 
        push    format                  ; pass the format string 
        call    sscanf                  ; convert it to floating point
```

But `format` and `dword [ecx + 4]` should be swapped!  Also, you put the pointer of the parameter table into `ecx` but `ecx` is a volatile register so `printf` clobbers it.  So either put `[ebp + 12]` into a non volatile register such ad `esi` or just mov that pointer into `ecx` before the call to `sscanf`  But you still have a problem, the first parameter is the exe name, not your passed number...

Fist parameter will be + 4.. try this:

```
    mov     ecx, [ebp + 12]
    push    temp                    ; pass the address of the destination
    push    format         ;pass the format string  
    push    dword [ecx + 4] ;; pass the first command line parameter                 ;
    call    sscanf                  ; convert it to floating point 
    add     esp, 12
```

Comment: I changed the order that I pushed the parameters to what you said, and it worked. Thanks!